# Programmatically change Trading View Widget symbol

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I'm using the [free financial chart widget](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/) which provided by Trading View.

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_bbf10"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Track all markets on TradingView</span></a></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_bbf10"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Every time I want to change the symbol (programmatically), I have to call
`new TradingView.widget()`
with new symbol passed in the options.
It work correctly, showing the chart I want. Howerver, there is a problem. Everytime we call
`new TradingView.widget()`
It will append a  tag in the DOM
like image below
[image: style tag]

Is there anyway I can directly change the symbol without calling `new TradingView.widget()` ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way in React! I assume the same direction would work for vanilla JS.

You can change the symbol by using a template literal.

1. Create a variable `var chartSymbol = "BITSTAMP:XRPUSD";`
2. Set the value for the symbol key in the TradingView widget to the variable using a template literal. `` "symbol": `${chartSymbol}` `` . Notice the backticks
3. Whatever you set the variable to, the TV chart will update the chart symbol to!
4. You can use an input and a button to enable the user to change the chart in a way you can see and control

Below I copy pasted my working component in React for reference. By default XRP is loaded into the chart. By clicking the ETH  & BTC buttons, you can programmatically see the chart change to ETH & BTC symbols appropriately. The `// @ts-ignore` is because I use typescript. You can ignore those unless you use Typescript as well

```
    import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

    let tvScriptLoadingPromise: any;

    export default function TradingViewWidget(props: any) {
    const onLoadScriptRef = useRef();
    const [chartSymbol, setChartSymbol] = useState("BITSTAMP:XRPUSD");

    // @ts-ignore
    useEffect(() => {
    // @ts-ignore
    onLoadScriptRef.current = createWidget;

    if (!tvScriptLoadingPromise) {
      tvScriptLoadingPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.id = "tradingview-widget-loading-script";
        script.src = "https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js";
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.onload = resolve;

        document.head.appendChild(script);
      });
    }

    tvScriptLoadingPromise.then(() => {
      // @ts-ignore
      onLoadScriptRef.current && onLoadScriptRef.current();
    });

    // @ts-ignore
    return () => (onLoadScriptRef.current = null);

    function createWidget() {
      if (
        document.getElementById("tradingview_3fe4f") &&
        "TradingView" in window
      ) {
        // @ts-ignore
        new window.TradingView.widget({
          autosize: true,
          symbol: `${chartSymbol}`,
          interval: "D",
          timezone: "Etc/UTC",
          theme: "dark",
          style: "1",
          locale: "en",
          enable_publishing: false,
          allow_symbol_change: true,
          container_id: "tradingview_3fe4f",
        });
       }
       }
       }, [chartSymbol]);



       return (
    <div
      className="tradingview-widget-container"
      style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
    >
      <button onClick={() => setChartSymbol("BITSTAMP:ETHUSD")}>ETH</button>
      <button onClick={() => setChartSymbol("BITSTAMP:BTCUSD")}>BTC</button>
      <div
        id="tradingview_3fe4f"
        style={{ height: "calc(100% - 32px)", width: "100%" }}
      />
      <div className="tradingview-widget-copyright">
        <a
          href="https://www.tradingview.com/"
          rel="noopener nofollow"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <span className="blue-text">Track all markets on TradingView</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
   );
    }
```